# Can I handle an ALT+TAB key press within my web page?

Tags: javascript, focus, window-managers

I realize this is a program switcher key combo in most OSs. Is there a possibility of capturing such an event in the web page via JavaScript?

Comment: Personally, I would say go for another key combo. If you do find a way to do this, it's just going to piss people off.

Comment: Sure - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but why would you want to?

Are you looking to do some onfocus or onblur? Maybe those events are useful for you.

Comment: disable the alt+tab feature altogether

Comment: onblur works for some reason! it is reliable to some extent. when we hit the windows key atleast in IE it loses focus...

Comment: When you figured out how to disable Alt+Tab, I felt a great disturbance in The Force, as if millions of voices suddenly cried out in terror and were suddenly silenced. I fear something terrible has happened.

Comment: I would find disabling alt-tab useful, because then I could pop up an ad that doesn't allow the user to use his computer until he buys $5 worth of my product or reboots. :P See the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can't capture this event, and of course you can't disable it. The browser doesn't own the computer, and *you* don't own the browser!

Why do you want to do this? Is this for an internal application, or one on the Internet, to be used by anyone?

Comment: internal application. Not for the internet.

Comment: So he does own the browser and transitively the computer :-)

Comment: Transitivity does is not implied. He may own the browser tab or window his user is using while he's using it, but that does not imply this application is so important that it supersedes anything else the user happens to be doing at the time.

Comment: This is truly an awful thing to do.